# Where Should Meteor Subscriptions Be Located in My Application?

Tags: meteor

I currently have my publications stored in `/server/publications.js`. I would like to store my client-side subscriptions in a central file too, like in `/client/subscriptions.js`. Is this a good design decision or are there more cons than pros? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could if you only want global, automatically-activated subscriptions. For some small apps that makes sense. As your code grows in complexity you may want more fine-grained control over your subscriptions. Generally speaking, you have three patters for placing subscriptions in your app (in order of granularity and control):

1. Globally (as suggested in your question)
2. In the [router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#subscriptions) - assuming you use iron router
3. In the [template](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/). Also see [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-joins) for additional template subscription examples.

While the community has recently fallen in love with template subscriptions, I'm not prepared to make a general recommendation that they are always they way to go. As you move up the subscription hierarchy, you lose some control but also gain reusability.

Let's take a simple example - imagine you have a social app and you have a list of friends. Let's say the majority of routes and templates assume the existence of your fiends' user data. If each template or route made the same subscription for this list, you'd end up with a lot of duplication and, potentially, a lot of unnecessary starting and stopping (this translates to server load and network bandwidth). On the other hand, had you made your friends a global subscription, those performance pitfalls could have been avoided.

Answer (score 4):

There are three main places you can subscribe to a Meteor collection.

---

### Globally

In this approach, you create subscriptions in a file somewhere on the client. Like your example, `subscriptions.js` is what most people name it. As long as it's in the `client` folder, it's fine.

```
Meteor.subscribe("posts");
```

Good candidates for this are collections that you will play around with on all or most of your templates. A friends list similar to Facebook, a feed of some kind.

### Router

If you're using something like iron-router or flow-router, you can subscribe to collections based on the URL. I prefer this approach the most. It's flexible, but not too taxing on performance. For example:

```
// Inside lib/router.js
FlowRouter.route('/blog/:postId', {
    subscriptions: function(params) {
        this.register('myPost', Meteor.subscribe('blogPost', params.postId));
    }
});
```

Now you can access the data you need using `myPost`. Very neat, and you can subscribe to as many things as you need.

### Template

This is the most flexible of all and the most taxing if you have multiple templates. Honestly, just avoid this approach because it's way too much work. 90% of the time I find myself using Router subscriptions.

```
Template.posts.onCreated(function () {
  // will re-run when the "limit" reactive variables changes
  instance.autorun(function () {

    // get the limit
    var limit = instance.limit.get();

    console.log("Asking for "+limit+" posts…")

    // subscribe to the posts publication
    var subscription = instance.subscribe('posts', limit);

    // if subscription is ready, set limit to newLimit
    if (subscription.ready()) {
      console.log("> Received "+limit+" posts. \n\n")
      instance.loaded.set(limit);
    } else {
      console.log("> Subscription is not ready yet. \n\n");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use template based subscriptions if possible. In that case, if you have `/client/templates/home.html`, you would put subscriptions related to that template in `/client/templates/home.js` for example.

```
Template.home.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe('somePublication');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the better way to manage the subscriptions is using [the template subscription pattern](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) pattern

Snippet taken from the reference:

```
Template.posts.onCreated(function () {

  // 1. Initialization

  var instance = this;

  // initialize the reactive variables
  instance.loaded = new ReactiveVar(0);
  instance.limit = new ReactiveVar(5);

  // 2. Autorun

  // will re-run when the "limit" reactive variables changes
  instance.autorun(function () {

    // get the limit
    var limit = instance.limit.get();

    console.log("Asking for "+limit+" posts…")

    // subscribe to the posts publication
    var subscription = instance.subscribe('posts', limit);

    // if subscription is ready, set limit to newLimit
    if (subscription.ready()) {
      console.log("> Received "+limit+" posts. \n\n")
      instance.loaded.set(limit);
    } else {
      console.log("> Subscription is not ready yet. \n\n");
    }
  });

  // 3. Cursor

  instance.posts = function() { 
    return Posts.find({}, {limit: instance.loaded.get()});
  }

});
```